# How to work with collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Can anyone write mini-guide which explains how to work with collections in EF?

For example I have following models:

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public List<PostComment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class PostComment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public BlogPost ParentPost { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

And context class:

```
public class PostContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BlogPost> Posts { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Posts;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    }
}
```

What do I need to write in OnModelCreating method so that I can use Posts.Add and etc. everywhere in my code?

Comment: You should not write in that method in order to add entity to your dbsets. Are you experimentig any issues?

Comment: @FabioCarello I have issue "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",  when i try to get post.Comments.Count (some posts with comments were added before).  That's why I asked the question.

Comment: "mini-guide which explains how to work with collections in EF?" Far too broad. This particular area is going to be similar to EF6.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are my tips for working with navigation properties in Entity Framework Core.

**Tip 1:** Initialize collections

```
class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Initialize to prevent NullReferenceException
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; } = new List<Comment>();
}

class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }

    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }        
}
```

**Tip 2:** Build using the `HasOne` and `WithMany` or `HasMany` and `WithOne` methods

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder model)
{
    model.Entity<Post>()
        .HasMany(p => p.Comments).WithOne(c => c.Post)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.PostId);
}
```

**Tip 3:** Eagerly load the collection

```
var posts = db.Posts.Include(p => p.Comments);
```

**Tip 4:** Explicitly load if you didn't eagerly

```
db.Comments.Where(c => c.PostId == post.Id).Load();
```

Comment: Thank you! It works for me. But now I have a new question, what do i need to do with collections of standart types, like "List<string>"? I can't do InverseReference, because string has no property like "c.Post" in your example. To solve this i wrote this code: http://pastebin.com/3w7xCQ2k
But is it right way? How can I make it simplier? I really want to use smth like this "public ICollection<string> Tags { get; set; } = new List<string>();"

Comment: @neonhash They're not currently supported. You have to wrap them inside of an entity type. E.g. `class StringValue { string Value { get; set; } }`

Comment: Just a note to say thanks, this is the clearest example of how to get this working I found.

Comment: I'm still getting null reference exceptions on nested navigation properties. I've initialized the navigation properties to new List<T>()s without change. Any ideas?

Comment: More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36134652/system-argumentnullexception-when-using-includethen

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `Comments`navigation property does not works properly. Try to provide to `BlogPost` model the actual referencig field to `PostComment` table. Also rename the navigation property in PostComments for the EF naming compliance.

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public int PosCommentId {get; set; }
    public List<PostComment> PostComments { get; set; }
}
```

If this neither works you have to define manually your relationship, but before help in this, you'd better provide the schema of this two tables in your db.

**UPDATE 01:**

First tip:
You are using singular named tables. This is not compliant to EF naming convention. Pluralization has to be turned off. Just put this line in `OnModelCreating` method.

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

Second tip:
My previous advice was totally wrong **do not consider it anymore**, just use your old models schema. Now, assuming a one-to-many relationship between comment and post:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Entity<PostComment>().HasRequired<BlogPost>(c => c.ParentPost)
            .WithMany(p => p.Comments);

    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

}
```

For more INFOs :

[EF one-to-many relationship tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

[Relationship and navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564)

[Configuring Relationships with the Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx)

Comment: It has not worked for me. I added Comments DbSet and used this code:  http://pastebin.com/5vFcJrZu , it works, but is it right way?

Comment: Are you trying to manually set the relationship? I don't think it's definitively a good idea. Could you post the db schema for this two tables?

Comment: Yes, I could: pastebin.com/Ti6dUjEv

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on answers from @FabioCarello and @bricela, I recommend using the **virtual** keyword on **Navigation Properties**:

```
public virtual ICollection<Comment> { get; set; }
```

This will allow **Lazy Loading**, which means that the collections/references will be loaded only upon first call and not during first data retrieve. That is very useful to avoid, for example, stack overflows on recursive references.

No **Fluent** is necessary for simple **one-to-many** relationships like yours, unless you need non-standard behaviors like explicitly requiring non-nullable references.

You can also make explicit uses of **foreign keys** which is useful so you don't have to load the parent when you only need its **Id**:

```
public class PostComment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public BlogPost ParentPost { get; set; }
    // //
    public int? ParentPostId { get; set; }
    // //
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This was likely downvoted (not by me) because this question is about EF7, which does [not currently support lazy loading](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3312).