# Include not including navigation property unless ToList is called

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF7 beta 7. I have a few forum style tables with a navigation property between them, along with a relationship set up in the `OnModelCreating` method of the context:

```
public class Forum
{
    public int ForumId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; } =  new List<Topic>();
}

public class Topic
{
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int ForumId { get; set; }
    public Forum Forum { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Forum> Forums { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Topic> Topics { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Forum>()
                    .Collection(f => f.Topics)
                    .InverseReference(t => t.Forum)
                    .ForeignKey(t => t.ForumId);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get a list of `Forum` with a count of the `Topic`:

```
var forums = _context.Forums.Include(f => f.Topics)
                            .Select(f => new 
                                {
                                    f.Title,
                                    f.ForumId,
                                    f.Topics.Count
                                });
```

When I run this as is, <strike>I get an `ArgumentNullException`</strike> I get an empty collection because it doesn't seem to actually eagerly load the `Topic`s. I have checked in `Sql Profiler` and confirmed that it's only running the select to get the `Forum`'s and no second select for the `Topic`'s.

If I call `ToList` before the `Select` as such

```
var forums = _context.Forums.Include(f => f.Topics)
                            .ToList()
                            .Select(f => new 
                                {
                                    f.Title,
                                    f.ForumId,
                                    f.Topics.Count
                                });
```

it will include the `Topic`'s and the code runs, however that defeats the purpose because that causes it to enumerate all forums with all topics and *then* count, instead of running the `Count` on the database. Is this a bug with `Include`, or am I using `Include` wrong?

Comment: I haven't worked with EF7, only 6 so maybe it changed, but doesn't your navigation property need to be `virtual` in order to support both eager and lazy loading?

Comment: @dman2306 I just tried making them `virtual` and no change. I don't think that's required in EF 6 either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the relationship between Topics and Forum for `.Include` to work.

```
class YourContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
          // configure the relationship here
    }
}
```

See [How to work with collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290171/how-to-work-with-collections/30309381#30309381) for more tips on using collections.

**Another note**

By calling `.ToList()` immediately after `.Include(...)` you are forcing an early evaluation. The following projection in `.Select(...)` runs in-memory on the client side, rather than using EF7's query pipeline.

Also, make sure to add an initializer into your POCO definition.

```
public ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; } = new List<Topic>()
```

Comment: That other SO post is great, thanks, however it doesn't seem to help. I've added a relationship and initialized the collection and I'm still getting the same result (albeit an empty collection instead of a NRE). I've edited the relevant changes into the question.

Comment: You know what, it looks like the relationships are working, it's projections that aren't... I'm going to ask a new question for that. Thanks.