# Setting DTO property to a null value yields no results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core

Given the following DTO class:

```
public class DistrictDetailDTO
{
    public DistrictDetailDTO()
    {

    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CountyFP { get; set; }
    public long? EstStudentPop { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public short? Ranking { get; set; }
    public string RANumber { get; set; }
    public long? SchoolCount { get; set; }        
    public string Coop { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public virtual DirectorDTO Director { get; set; }
    public virtual AddressDTO Address { get; set; }
}
```

The following LINQ query fails to return any results when the district's Coop property is null...

```
var district = from districts in _ctx.District
                        where districts.Id == id
                        select new DistrictDetailDTO
                        {
                            Id = districts.Id,
                            CountyFP = districts.County.FIPSCode,
                            EstStudentPop = districts.EstStudentPop,
                            Name = districts.Name,
                            Ranking = districts.Ranking,
                            RANumber = districts.RANumber,
                            SchoolCount = districts.SchoolCount,
                            Address = new AddressDTO {
                                Line1 = districts.Address.Line1,
                                Line2 = districts.Address.Line2,
                                City = districts.Address.City,
                                State = districts.Address.State,
                                Zipcode = districts.Address.Zipcode
                            },
                            Coop = (districts.Coop==null) ? "None" : districts.Coop.Name,
                            County = districts.County.Name,
                            Director = new DirectorDTO {
                                Email = districts.Director.Email,
                                ImgUrl = districts.Director.ImgUrl,
                                Name = districts.Director.Name,
                                Phone = districts.Director.Phone
                            }
                        };
```

If I remove the Coop property from the DTO and the query it returns as it should.. what can I do to fix this? The conditional ?: is not working.

Comment: Have you tried to look into SQL generated by EF? I bet, you will find more detail in it.

Comment: Please show the mapping of the association between `District` and `Coop`.

Comment: From your code, `where districts.Id == id` the result depends on Id, not Coop. Are you sure the query is not returning result for some other reasons?

Comment: Coop is a navigation property of  the District entity/model.... from the District entity class: [ForeignKey("CoopId")]
        [InverseProperty("District")]
        public virtual Coop Coop { get; set; }     --- I should also note that not all District's have a Coop associated with them, in which case CoopId (int?) and Coop itself are expected to be null.

Comment: Are you actually using the EF7 beta?

Comment: Yes I am using ef7 beta-8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to work with collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290171/how-to-work-with-collections)