# What is the correct way to configure a one-to-many relationship with Entity Framework 7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a setup where an Integration object has many HeaderMap objects.  The classes are setup as shown below.  When I call `integration.HeaderMaps` I get a return count of 0, even though the database clearly shows there should be 1 result.  I am using Entity Framework 7.  What am I missing in a properly setup one-to-many relationship?

```
public class Integrations
{
    public Integrations()
    {
        HeaderMaps = new HashSet<HeaderMaps>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int IntegrationId { get; set; }

    ...

    [InverseProperty("Integration")]
    public virtual ICollection<HeaderMaps> HeaderMaps { get; set; }
}

public class HeaderMaps
{
    [Key]
    public int HeaderMapId { get; set; }
    public int IntegrationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IntegrationId")]
    [InverseProperty("HeaderMaps")]
    public virtual Integrations Integration { get; set; }
}

public partial class Dev_IntegrationsContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(@"uid=sa;pwd=******;Initial Catalog=Dev_Integrations; Data Source=*******;Min Pool Size=10;Max Pool Size=150;");
    }

    public virtual DbSet<HeaderMaps> HeaderMaps { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Integrations> Integrations { get; set; }
}
```

Runtime:

```
var integration = context.Integrations.First(i => i.IntegrationId == 4);
integration.HeaderMaps // returns a count of 0
context.HeaderMaps.First().Integration // there is only 1 row in the table, and it returns an Integrations object with id of 4
```

SQL:

```
select * from HeaderMaps where IntegrationId = 4; -- returns 1 record
```

Comment: Why not debug EF to see what TSQL it executed?

Comment: Are you trying to lazy load the `HeaderMaps` collection?  I don't believe that's implemented yet in EF7

Comment: @Erik Good thought, I'm still new enough that I'm not sure how to see the TSQL, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Moho it uses whatever the default configuration is. I haven't explicitly set lazy loading, does it do lazy loading by default?

Comment: @NathanHanna http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mpeder/archive/2014/06/16/how-to-see-the-actual-sql-query-generated-by-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: @NathanHanna lazy loading isn't implemented in EF7 at this time https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap

Answer (score 0):

Naming convention is to have singular class names and the generated tables will be pluralized. Try changing Integrations to be Integration and HeaderMaps to be HeaderMap. Can you also post your DbContext code? Is it possible that HeaderMaps isn't declared in there?

Comment: I added the db context above, also the relationship works in the opposite direction (see runtime example), so I'm assuming there is just some configuration that is missing for getting the records from the 'one' side of the one-to-many.  I will try the singular class names and let you know how it goes.

Comment: also, if it helps, I generated this code using the database first approach through the dnx command

Comment: Get rid of the `HeaderMaps = new HashSet<HeaderMaps>();` in the Integrations constructor. I've never had to declare the collection in the constructor before.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the problem is not the configuration of your relationship. You need to use `.Include()`

```
var integration = context.Integrations
     .Include(i => i.HeaderMaps)
     .First(i => i.IntegrationId == 4);
```

See [How to work with collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290171/how-to-work-with-collections/30309381#30309381)