# System.ArgumentNullException when using IncludeThen

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an Code First model: [image: Code First Model] I am attempting to use `Include()` and `IncludeThen()` and get a `System.ArgumentNullException` .

Here are the entities (let me know if you'd like more of the model):

```
 public class Area
{
    public Area()
    {
        Geocode = new List<Geocode>();
    }

    public int AreaId { get; set; }
    public int InfoId { get; set; }
    public string AreaDescription { get; set; }
    public string Polygon { get; set; }
    public string Circle { get; set; }
    public List<Geocode> Geocode { get; set; }
    public string Altitude { get; set; }
    public string Ceiling { get; set; }
}

    public class Geocode
{
    public Geocode(string valueName, string value
        )
    {
        ValueName = valueName;
        Value = value;
    }

    public int GeocodeId { get; set; }
    public int AreaId { get; set; }
    public string ValueName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the calling code:

```
context.Alerts.Include(f => f.Infos)
                .ThenInclude(f => f.Areas)
                .ThenInclude(f => f.Geocode);// When I comment out this line it does not error, just doesn't load the Geocode navigation property.
```

Here is a stack trace:

> at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(ConstructorInfo constructor, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.CreateMaterializeExpression(IEntityType entityType, Expression valueBufferExpression, Int32[] indexMap)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.MaterializerFactory.CreateMaterializer(IEntityType entityType, SelectExpression selectExpression, Func`3 projectionAdder, IQuerySource querySource)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.IncludeExpressionVisitor.d__13.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Dynamic.Utils.CollectionExtensions.ToReadOnly[T](IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.NewArrayInit(Type type, IEnumerable`1 initializers)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.IncludeExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression expression)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.ExpressionVisitorBase.Visit(Expression expression)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.IncludeNavigations(IncludeSpecification includeSpecification, Type resultType, LambdaExpression accessorLambda, Boolean querySourceRequiresTracking)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.IncludeNavigations(QueryModel queryModel, IReadOnlyCollection`1 includeSpecifications)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.IncludeNavigations(QueryModel queryModel, IReadOnlyCollection`1 includeSpecifications)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.IncludeNavigations(QueryModel queryModel)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1.<CompileQuery>b__0()
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>      at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.IncludableQueryable`2.GetEnumerator()
>      at WeatherMonitoringConsole.Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\ehasson\Source\Workspaces\Marketing\WeatherMonitoring\WeatherMonitoringConsole\Program.cs:line 32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was I needed a default constructor on each entity.